# Append data to excel sheet if created using ClosedXML in c#

Tags: c#, excel, worksheet-function, closedxml

I am writing an application in which I need to store data cell values into excel sheet. Everything is working fine but the problem is everytime I run the application, it overwrites the existing data.

So far the code I have taken from Github:

```
  var workbook = new XLWorkbook();
  var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sample Sheet");
  worksheet.Cell("A1").Value = this.textBox1.Text;
  worksheet.Cell("B1").Value = this.textBox2.Text;
  worksheet.Cell("C1").Value = this.textBox3.Text;
  worksheet.Cell("D1").Value = col1;
  worksheet.Cell("E1").Value = col2;
  worksheet.Cell("F1").Value = this.textBox6.Text;
  workbook.SaveAs("HelloWorld.xlsx");
```

Note: I don't want to save data using datatable or anything. I just want to get values from textboxes and append them to the existing sheet. I have visited many stackoverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29186142/how-to-append-a-new-row-to-an-excel-file-using-c-sharp-and-closedxml) but they doesn't helped me much.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
var wb = new XLWorkbook("Path to file");
IXLWorksheet Worksheet = wb.Worksheet("Tab name");
int NumberOfLastRow = Worksheet.LastRowUsed().RowNumber();
IXLCell CellForNewData = Worksheet.Cell(NumberOfLastRow + 1, 1);

CellForNewData.InsertData(your_data);
```

Answer (score -1):

You are explicitly storing the values in row 1 of the spreadsheet. If you want to append the values, you'll have to increment the row number and store the values in the appropriate cells.