# How to insert data to excel sheet using loop

Tags: c#, excel

i'm trying to insert some data to my excel sheet.

My main code returns true/false statement and i need to save that statements to my Registers.xls file.

How do i read and write data from same excel. (Sorry for poor english)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Excel.Application xlApp;
            Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook;
            Excel.Worksheet xlWorksheet;
            Excel.Range range;

            xlApp = new Excel.Application();
            xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"E:\VScode\Registers.xls");
            xlWorksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkbook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

            range = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;
            int cl = range.Rows.Count;
            string result;
            string strRegist;

            for (int i = 1; i <= cl;i++)
            {
                strRegist = (string)(range.Cells[i,3] as Excel.Range).Value2;                
                result = Convert.ToString(Program.CheckRegister(strRegist));
                //Insert result to my sheet
                Console.WriteLine(result);
            }
            xlWorkbook.Close(true, null, null);
            xlApp.Quit();

            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorksheet);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkbook);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Comment: If you are trying to insert existing worksheet this may help. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29186142/how-to-append-a-new-row-to-an-excel-file-using-c-sharp-and-closedxml)

Answer (score 0):

You could add your data into a datatable and then convert that to an excelsheet and adding that sheet into w/e workbook you want.

```
using OfficeOpenXml;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
void SaveTableAsExcelSheet(DataTable dt, string filePath)
{
    var fi = new FileInfo(filePath);
    using (ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage(fi))
    {
        ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(dt.TableName);
        ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dt, true);
        pck.Save();
    }
}
```